# Copy fields from one table to another when they do not share all fields

Tags: sql

I have two similar tables, A and B.

Table A and B have a lot of fields in common, but there are some fields in A that do not exist in B and vice versa.

I want to transfer the shared fields' content from table A to table B, without getting something like `#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`, of course.

Is this possible?

---

something like this:

`insert into A (select * from B)` => `insert into A ({fields_in_common}) (select {fields_in_common} from B)`

Comment: transfer, or just view all of the fields from both tables? Can you list both of the tables fields it will make this a bit easier

Comment: @Ferenjito Pleasae share query

Comment: There is no query yet, that is the problem

Comment: Do the 2 tables have the same data structure ?

Comment: You need to list those columns explicitly. There is no magic in any DBMS (which you failed to mention) that does a matching based on column names.

Comment: I said, they 'have a lot of fields in common', which means afain, they share some data structure and that is what my question is about.

Comment: You were already given an answer by @a_horse_with_no_name. You need to explicitly write them down in a statement. If you would like to get matching column names to make your statement easier you could check in (PostgreSQL) `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: Data structure does not mean data fields. Also, please mention your DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try insert into

```
INSERT INTO TableB (b1, b2, b3)
SELECT a1, a2, a3
FROM   TableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data structure of your 2 tables `A` and `B` are the same, then this should work fine without the problem you mentioned:

```
INSERT INTO A
     SELECT * 
     FROM A
     INNER JOIN B
                 ON A.field1=B.field1
                 AND A.field2=B.field2
                 ...
                 ...
                 AND A.fieldn=B.fieldn
```